# PHP preg_match not returning correct array

Tags: php, html, arrays, regex, preg-match

So I have been reading up on regex, I used a great tutorial on youtube that explained it very good and so I decided to try some using http://www.phpliveregex.com/ and it worked out great on the website but not in my php code.

So what I want is to find the name of the winner in some html code. This website I'm going through is just here for testing purposes and only run on my local machine ^^

```
<span style="width: 45%; float: left; text-align: left">
  <div class="team" style="float: left; margin-right: 10%; background: url('http://cdn.csgolounge.com/img/teams/Cloud9.jpg?41')"></div>
  <b>Cloud9 (win)</b><br><i>84%</i>      </span>
```

So what I start by doing is to sort out a word and a space and (win) that is surrounded by . I do this with:

```
preg_match("<b>\w+\s\D\w\w\w\D</b>", $comment1, $comment2);
```

$comment1 is the html code.

And then I preg_match it again to just retrieve the name of the winner with:

```
preg_match("[a-zA-Z]\w+", $comment2[0], $comment3);
```

which I then finish by echoing out comment2[0]

I have tries this on phpliveregex and it works great. But over at my website comment2[0] does not show anything.

I'm inserting the html code into a box on the local website that is then passed through to my code( I have checked and confirmed that this is working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not the entire solution but you should escape the slash in `</b>` in your first regex: `<\/b>`. Is this that first regex that is not working on your website?

Comment: The weird thing is that I'm telling PHP to put the result in comment2. But comment 2 is empty. Instead comment1 has what should be in comment2[0].

Also that change seems to have not made a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add delimiters around the regex:

```
preg_match("~<b>\w+\s\D\w\w\w\D</b>~", $comment1, $comment2);

preg_match("~[a-zA-Z]\w+~", $comment2[0], $comment3);
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit what difference the delimiters does(apart from solving my problem)?

Comment: @Thomja: Strange, it works fine for me. The delimiters are mandatory for regex with the functions `preg_xxxx`. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html

Comment: It worked for me as well. I just called the wrong variable.

I see that there are different delimiters, does it matter which one I use?

Comment: @Thomja: usualy the standard delimiter is `/` but using another one is usefull when the delimiter is present in the regex. It's the case for you, the `/` exists in `</b>` and using `~` prevents to escape the `/`